# Windows Server 2016 running off iSCSI BSOD after power loss

Tags: iscsi, windows-server-2016, server-crashes, bsod

I've got a setup where I'm hosting the Windows Server 2016 images on a Solaris 11 ZFS SAN over iSCSI.  These images began as baremetal installs then I used Clonezilla to clone them to the dedicated SAN volume.  Once I do this I remove the harddrive, change the boot device to the iSCSI controller, and the system boots fine.

SOMETIMES (I've done this process at least a dozen times) the system will blue screen on the first boot off iSCSI (PNP Detected Fatal Error), auto reboot, then boots fine.  I can then shutdown/startup or reboot the system as many times as I want and no crash.

PROBLEM: If the server loses power unexpectedly (press and hold power button, etc) then the system throws a BSOD every time and it's game over (I have to reimage the hard drive to the SAN).  I cannot reproduce this failure by powering off while the system is running from the hard drive.

Errata: It's a SuperMicro server with a Intel X540-AT2 NIC that I have the latest Intel Pro 22.7 drivers on.  No, this scenario shouldn't happen (UPS, common sense, etc) but it's a deliverable system and in this state is not satisfactorily reliable for me.

Your consideration and assistance with this issue is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is the blue screen the same after a power failure? Is there any more details you can give about the blue screen? Exact message; error codes; etc. are these systems booting UEFI or Legacy?

Comment: The blue screen only occurs after a power failure.  It just gives the error message "stop code: PNP Detected Fatal Error".  This happens after the Windows logo is presented and then the loading indicator circles begin animating.  It happens roughly 20 seconds after the logo displays.  They are booting Legacy.